Running with remote executor does not execute remotely
I've created the following rule to generate a remote execution platform:
def _remote_execution_platform_impl(ctx: AnalysisContext) -> list[Provider]:
    constraint_list = [c[ConstraintValueInfo] for c in ctx.attrs.constraints]
    cfg = ConfigurationInfo(constraints = {c.setting.label: c for c in constraint_list}, values = {})

    name = ctx.label.raw_target()
    platform = ExecutionPlatformInfo(
        label = name,
        configuration = cfg,
        executor_config = CommandExecutorConfig(
            local_enabled = False,
            remote_enabled = True,
            remote_execution_properties = {},
            remote_execution_use_case="buck2"
        ),
    )

    return [
        DefaultInfo(),
        platform,
        PlatformInfo(label = str(name), configuration = cfg)
    ]

remote_execution_platform = rule(
    impl = _remote_execution_platform_impl,
    attrs = {
        "constraints": attrs.list(attrs.dep(providers = [ConstraintValueInfo]))
    },
)

Next, I define a rule to register multiple platforms:
def _platforms_impl(ctx: AnalysisContext):
    platforms = [dep[ExecutionPlatformInfo] for dep in ctx.attrs.deps]
    return [
        DefaultInfo(),
        ExecutionPlatformRegistrationInfo(platforms = platforms)
    ]

platforms = rule(
    impl = _platforms_impl,
    attrs = {
        "deps": attrs.list(attrs.dep(providers = [ExecutionPlatformInfo]))
    }
)

and then use this in a BUCK file (platforms/BUCK):
remote_execution_platform(name = "remote", constraints = ["root//constraints:ip_required"])

platforms(name = "platforms", deps=[":remote"])

Now, I have a simple sh_binary:
sh_binary(
    name = "host_test",
    main = "demo.sh",
    target_compatible_with = ["root//constraints:ip_required"]
)

Then I run this in the natural way:
buck2 run //utils:ip_test --target-platforms root//platforms:remote

It should print the hostname of the executor, but it prints the hostname of my local system. I confirmed that I see nothing in the remote executor config. I have localhost port 8980 forwarded to the remote executor, so my Buck2 config has:
[buck2_re_client]
action_cache_address = grpc://localhost:8980
engine_address = grpc://localhost:8980
cas_address = grpc://localhost:8980
tls = false

How can I fix _remote_execution_platform_impl to actually execute on the remote platform?

To register execution platforms you should pass //platforms:platforms to buck.execution_platforms buckconfig. Maybe it's the problem since I don't see it in your config.
Also buck2 audit execution-platform-resolution //utils:ip_test --target-platforms root//platforms:remote output would be helpful here.
